# How to load Angular components using router-outlet

Tags: angular, typescript, components, router

The `Product component` page isn't updated if `Product 2 Component` is clicked after `Product 1 Component`. I have to click `Hello Component` and only then `Product 2 Component` to make sure `Product component` page is updated with the ID number.

By other words, the `Product` component is only updated if I click:

1. `Product 1 Component`
2. `Hello Component`
3. `Product 2 Component`

[image]

How to fix the problem? Here is the Stackblitz project:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-insynj?file=src%2Fproduct%2Fproduct.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yzcvdr) Normally it is working . Your missing is that you can't redirect in same component. That is why you thought wrongly. give function to each click and

```
<nav> 
  <a  class="btn btn-tab" (click)="onChange('/hello')">Hello Component</a>  
  <a  class="btn btn-tab"(click)="onChange('/product/1')">Product 1 Component</a>
  <a  class="btn btn-tab"(click)="onChange('/product/2')">Product 2 Component</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

use this in component.ts

```
constructor(private _router:Router){}
onChange(param){
  this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
  this._router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
  this._router.navigate([param]);
}
```